# How to access parts of localhost with device

Tags: wamp, moodle

I've pulled the latest stable MOODLE_21_STABLE branch to my WAMP server localhost location, all installed and configured successfully, works in browsers as per usual. I'm poking around theming now, and would like to test out device-specific themes.

SO questions helped me successfully connect to my localhost via iPhone Safari and Android Chrome, I can navigate the various projects and tools I have on localhost - all of that works wonderfully (successful URL eg: http://192.168.123.135/ - this is the root WAMP page).

Next, I tried to access my Moodle install via Safari (URL for reference: http://192.168.123.135/moodle/moodle2/htdocs/), but Safari prompts an error:

"Cannot Open Page. Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server."

The page beneath the prompt reads:

"Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through 'http://localhost/moodle/moodle212/htdocs' address, sorry. Please notify server administrator."

Two things to note:

- Safari re-writes the IP address portion of the URL to 'localhost'  for the failed Moodle URLs I've been trying to enter, when it prompts the error. My own project URLs keep their IP portion.
- The above 'suggested' address in the page error also delivers the same error message again.

I feel like I'm inches away from awesomeness here, does anyone have any advice/ideas as to how I can access my Moodle install on a WAMP localhost (or similar), when browsing via device?

Is there some server setting I need to dis/enable?

Is this likely to be a Moodle specific issue, or is there something about accessing server locations in this way that is troublesome/not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both $CFG->wwwroot and the IP address of the Apache vhost in the WAMP configuration files are set to 192.168.123.135. Also possibly the hostname too. It sounds like you have a config issue with internal and external DNS names not resolving in quite the same way. Apache is probably the culprit.

Are you referring to desktop Safari installed on the same machine as WAMP?

Comment: Nice, I will tamper with this in an hour or so, and no it isn't desktop Safari - all desktop access is fine, its only from mobile browsers that the pages fail to be served.

Comment: Nearly there, your solution did work, there's just one side effect now - I enjoy the convenience of using 'localhost' to access anything on localhost (via desktop) but I can only access Moodle via the IP address now (all other personal projects still work with localhost). I updated my Windows hosts file to include: 192.168.123.135     localhost, to no avail. I can live with using the IP address but if you have a solution so I can continue to use localhost from my desktop - that would be super.

Comment: The only way to do that and also be able to get to the sites from the network via iPhone etc is to set up a local DNS server within your network and assign a proper domain name (e.g. 'localhost') to 192.168.123.135. I think the easiest way would be to load the open source DD-WRT firmware onto your router, which comes with a built in DNS server (http://cybernetnews.com/local-internal-dns-ddwrt/). This assumes you have a compatible router, of course, but most are. Check here to see if your is: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database